# Topological order and entanglement in quantum quench problem

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, quantum-information, topological-order

I would like to ask about useful reviews, must-read papers on the study of topological order and entanglement in quantum quench problems that give a good introduction to the topic.

Comment: I'm not actually sure whether this is the kind of resource recommendation that fits on this site, but in case it is on topic, I'm adding the post notice.